# How to convert string to unicode using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, unicode

Here I want to convert my string to unicode. I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 version. In SQL Server its much more easy:

**Example**:

```
   sql = N'select * from tabletest'; /* For nvarchar/nchar/ntext */
```

**OR**

```
   sql = U'select * from tabletest'; /* For varchar/char/text */
```

**Question**: How can I do the above conversion in PostgreSQL?

Comment: What is the database encoding? Try `\l` at the psql prompt or query `show server_encoding;`.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto, Database encoding is "UTF8".

Comment: So your script file is not UTF-8? Or you are trying to enter it at the terminal which is not UTF-8? What is the problem?

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto, File is not UTF-8.

Comment: The best and easiest is to save it as UTF-8. Any decent editor can do it.

Comment: "Unicode" is not a thing that can be converted to. You'll have to describe more clearly what you want.

Comment: @deceze SQL Server uses the Unicode term as synonym to UTF-16.

Comment: @Clodoaldo As most MS products do, yes. That still doesn't make it any more meaningful in the Postgres world. ;)

Comment: @deceze I just wanted to show that as I understand his problem is just of encoding. Nothing to do with Unicode. That is, SQL Server users are mislead by wrong terminology.

Comment: "Unicode" can mean: utf-8, utf-16, utf-32, ucs-2, ucs-4. Which is it?

Comment: @Craig Ringer, utf-8.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PostgreSQL databases have a native character type, the "server encoding". It is usually utf-8.

All text is in this encoding. Mixed encoding text is not supported, except if stored as `bytea` (i.e. as opaque byte sequences).

You can't store "unicode" or "non-unicode" strings, and PostgreSQL has no concept of "varchar" vs "nvarchar". With utf-8, characters that fall in the 7-bit ASCII range (and some others) are stored as a single byte, and wider chars require more storage, so it's just automatic. utf-8 requires more storage than ucs-2 or utf-16 for text that is all "wide" characters, but less for text that's a mixture.

PostgreSQL automatically converts to/from the client's text encoding, using the `client_encoding` setting. There is no need to convert explicitly.

If your client is "Unicode" (which Microsoft products tend to say when they mean UCS-2 or UTF-16), then most client drivers take care of any utf-8 <--> utf-16 conversion for you.

So you should not need to care, so long as your client does I/O with correct charset options and sets a correct `client_encoding` that matches the data its actually sends on the wire. (This is automatic with most client drivers like PgJDBC, nPgSQL, or the Unicode psqlODBC driver).

See:

- [character set support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html)