# Oracle SQL Statement select u'' from dual

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, unicode

I've searched long and hard on the list of oracle keywords and reserved words but to no avail.

What does the part `u''` mean?

I've been trying to convert Oracle database objects to PostgreSQL. I've come across a statement `Coalesce(some_field,u'')` and this statement returns a syntax error in Postgres

Coalesce is supposed to return null if none of the parameter returns any non-null value. But when executing `select u'' from dual`, I could see that the result is null. I'm not sure why they included it in the statement `Coalesce(some_field,u'')`.

Is It safe to assume the statement will work if the `u''` part didn't exist in the statement at all?

Guys I've met, completely deny the existence of such usage in oracle `u''` googling didn't turn out to be fruitful, coz I didn't know the concept.

Note:
but when executing `select Coalesce('sampleee text',u'') from dual`

I get the following error:

```
ORA-12704: character set mismatch
12704. 00000 -  "character set mismatch"
```

but when executing `select Coalesce(u'sampleee text',u'') from dual`, I get 'sampleee text' as result and no errors...

So I suspect it has something to do with type casting to unicode character set. But I may be wrong.

A̶n̶y̶ ̶O̶r̶a̶c̶l̶e̶r̶s̶/̶T̶O̶M̶(̶T̶h̶e̶O̶r̶a̶c̶l̶e̶M̶a̶s̶t̶e̶r̶s̶)̶ ̶w̶h̶o̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶c̶l̶e̶a̶r̶-̶u̶p̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶d̶i̶l̶e̶m̶m̶a̶?̶

**Update:**
it seems the u is a prefix to denote that the string includes Unicode character strings... `select chr(222),u'\00DE' from dual;` [refer this](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/203822/)

And I'd appreciate any PostgreSQL fanboys to suggest me an alternative solution to convert the same to Postgres

Comment: `select coalesce(some_field, '')` should do it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, The first parameter of the Coalesce() function is a table's field which may be of some type (probably unicode charset)... so removing the `u` will end up throwing the charset mismatch error as I mentioned in the note...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, any explanations for the character `u` in oracle?

Comment: You asked... for a Postgres ... solution...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, even in postgres, the first parameter might be of some type and if the second parameter didn't match with the first one, it might throw up errors right? so can you point me to an alternative to `u` in postgresql... maybe `::text` or `::u` ie `''::u` or something like that...

Comment: The first parameter can be any character column. That won't result in an error. I have no idea what the `u''` is in Oracle

Comment: Prefix `u` is related to Unicode. [link 1](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4072939?start=0&tstart=0), [link 2](http://www.howardsmith.net/manuals/Oracle_PL_SQL_Programming.pdf).

Comment: (Also, bear in mind that in Oracle, an empty string `''` and `NULL` are equivalent, for weird historical reasons, whereas in most databases, including Postgres, they're different.)

Comment: I had a word with our Oracle DBA, and he was reasonably baffled by the `u''`; he'd never seen it before. However, after some digging around, he seems reasonably confident that the u is a short form of the [UNISTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions204.htm) function. It certainly seems to act the same. Neither of us can find any official Oracle docs about the `u` version, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a comment. What @a_horse_with_no_name is true, `coalesce(some_fild, '')` should work.

Unlike Oracle, Postgres conversions are [implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014147/how-to-convert-string-to-unicode-using-postgresql).

For explicit conversion, use `convert_to(string text, dest_encoding name)`.
Reference is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER).